# How to update or add a column in datagridview

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005

Using VB.NET and SQL Server 2005

In DataGridView n number of rows was displaying. Suppose I edit some value in the datagridview cell then I click save means it should update in the table also. Suppose I click 
add button means it should add a new row in datagridview.

How to write a code for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use a strongly typed `Dataset`, fill it and bind it do your datagridview. The generated `TableAdapter` does the basic CRUD for you.

Since you didn't provide any further information, this is the best advice I can give. Google for a tutorial, should be very easy to find.